# What to do when people fight a war using votes, flags and SO powers?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, downvotes

Once in a while a little war breaks loose. In this particular case a user copied the answer of somebody else (Answer 2) in his own answer (Answer 1) and asked Answer 2 to be deleted (which it was). Then a request for undelete votes was made in the chat, after which Answer 2 was undeleted and Answer 1 was downvoted into oblivion. Meanwhile also comments talking about it got flagged/deleted, people started voting to delete Answer 1 and after a few hours the entire question is a mess and everybody is mad at each other.

But Answer 1 was, although not the best one, a perfectly valid answer, and the accepted one. And I don't think flags and SO powers are meant to show your appreciation of anyone's character.

Thing is, I've been thinking on how I could report this and prevent that feelings ruin that poor question further. But there seems no accurate flag for this. So how would I report this in the future?

The question I'm talking about: [Conditionally replace elements of vector based on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908364/conditionally-replace-elements-of-vector-based-on-index) (also look at the revision history of that accepted answer).

The sentiments are clear in the R chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/106

Please keep in mind I'm not taking sides here, and I do understand the frustrations about the behaviour of the person who wrote Answer 1. I just want to know how to stop this before it gets out of hand.

Comment: Has there been any intervention from a moderator so far?

Comment: @E_net4 some of the flagged comments were removed, and I believe Brad Larson is a mod. I've seen him pass by in the chat, so I guess he's on it.

Comment: Every single post that has been deleted on that question was deleted by it's author.  No post has ever been deleted by anyone else.

Comment: @Servy I arrived at the question and saw a lot of carnage. I refer to the transcript where David Arenburg asks for undelete votes. I might have misinterpreted a flag, but I can't see all the action. There's been flags thrown around, but if you say that was only on comments, then I misunderstood a few things. updated to reflect this

Comment: @JorisMeys The post was *undeleted* by someone other than the author.  It wasn't *deleted* by someone other than the author.  The other deleted it, and then 3 other people undeleted it.  Other than that all that's on that question is people voting on posts, and commenting to explain why they're voting on posts, which all seems sensible enough (I couldn't comment on the actual merits of either, not being knowledgeable about the subject matter.).

Comment: @Servy The guy in discussion asked nicola to delete his answer by claiming that it is the same as his (while it is not even remotely), so nicola deleted it because he is naive. The this guy added nicolas answer to his own (without even mentioning nicola). There are tons of deleted comments there that you don't see right now because they were flagged and deleted by mods. nicolas answer was undeleted by myself and another two users and he [thanked us later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908364/conditionally-replace-elements-of-vector-based-on-index#comment76833398_44910665).

Comment: @DavidArenburg My point still stands.  This isn't people abusive moderation privileges to delete answers.  I certainly believe your explanation.  There's still a difference (as far as how you react to the situation) between someone abusively casting delete votes on an appropriate answer and someone posting a comment asking the author to delete an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think things might be getting blown a little out of proportion here. The basic story is that someone posted an answer that was accepted. Others thought that the answer was flawed and downvoted it.

Some of the comments on that answer were fairly rude. They were flagged and removed. For the record, here are the deleted comments:

[image: Deleted comments]

I think most people can agree that those comments weren't too constructive and I agree with the decision to delete them when flagged.

At that point, the answerer was accused of "hiding behind flags", and the answer was linked in the R chatroom, which led to a series of downvotes against it. This user felt they were being targeted, which they kinda were, but we can't control how people vote. Meta-commentary about the votes was edited into the answer and rolled back.

I'm always a little uncomfortable with posts being linked in chatrooms and people skewing votes just by that visibility, but there's really nothing that can be done about that. It's the hostility in comments that I was more concerned about, and that has been taken care of.

As always, don't let things get personal, just downvote and / or flag and move on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And I agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: "*The basic story is that someone posted an answer that was accepted. Others thought that the answer was flawed and downvoted it.*" No. That not even remotely what happened. The answer actually got 4 upvotes at the beginning. The downvotes came after that user asked another user to delete his answer and then stole it. I don't think that most of these downvotes have much to do with the content of the answer, rather with OPs behavior. And either my comments were directed against that behaviour. The snap shot here should start from earlier comments in order to understand the context.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - They never asked nicola to delete their post. All they did was leave the following comment: "The idea is actually the same as what I already posted but with a different coding :-)", and nicola replied with "Oh, I see. There are a lot of answers and missed yours, sorry. You should use outer instead of mapply and check edge cases however. I'm gonna delete this answer soon."

Comment: (Cont. from previous comment) The "*`outer` is vectorized while `mapply` is a loop*" comment was directed to the comment before it rather to the answer.

Comment: Ok, so the post was deleted because of that deceiving and meaningless comment. It is pretty clear what they wanted nicola to do and that exactly what happened. nicola [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908364/conditionally-replace-elements-of-vector-based-on-index#comment76833398_44910665) agrees he shouldn't have done it.

Comment: I think you're reading malice into 989's actions where there was none. At worst, I think this was a misunderstanding.

Comment: So what was the point of that comment, please tell me. Also, why did he upvote nicolas answer when he decided to delete his answer?

Comment: And regarding "*and the answer was linked in the R chatroom*"- I didn't link the answer in the chatroom. I've only linked the deleted answer. Most of the downvotes received were prior to that link in the chatroom. I only linked the edit history afterwards in order to make a point (and again, I've linked only the edit history -  not the answer). But at no stage I've asked anyone to downvote or delete that answer. That wasn't my purpose. All I wanted is to undelete the deleted answer. I think the way you've phrased your answer is very misleading.